# TypeScript - How to use Generic in a Re-Usable React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-props

I have a reusable React Component. It has a few Props, which accept a Generic. This is the compoent:

```
export interface MappedObject {
  key: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  status: AppStatus;
}
export interface IProps<T> extends MappedObject {
  listing: T[];
  listingName: string;
  listingType?: boolean;
  listingStatus?: boolean;
}
```

I want my re-usable component to accept a Generic when referencing Props.

```
const AssociatedTableList: <T>(props: IProps<T>) => ReactElement<IProps<T>> = ({
  listing,
  listingName,
  listingType,
  listingStatus
}) => {
  const isListingAvailable = isEmpty(Array.isArray(listing));

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isListingAvailable && `There are no associated ${listingName} yet`}
      {isListingAvailable && (
        <table
          className="table table-borderless table-striped table-small"
          data-test="connections-listing-table"
        >
          <thead className="text-color-light-gray">
            <tr>
              <th>{`${listingName}`} Name</th>
              {listingType && <th>Type</th>}
              {listingStatus && <th>Status</th>}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {listing.map(({ type, status, name, key }) => ( // The error is in this properties
              <tr key={key} data-test="connections-listing-row">
                <td className="text-primary font-weight-medium w-25">{name}</td>
                <td>{type}</td>
                <td>{status}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot find name T
```

I tried extending it like this `T = {}` or `T as any` but no luck. I read about extending it, but I want it to be reusable by anyone. I am keen to have a type with all available types it can accept and extend it like `T extends AvailableGenericTypes`.

Do you have any idea, how I can do that? Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your generic constraint before the function:

```
const AssociatedTableList: <T>(p: IProps<T>) => React.ReactElement<IProps<T>> = ({ 
    list,
    listItem,
    listItemName,
    listItemStatus,
    listItemType
}) => {
    // your code
};
```

I personally prefer normal functions since they are more readable when using generics:

```
function AssociatedTableList<T>(props: IProps<T>): React.ReactElement<IProps<T>> {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. One small problem I have now is, I am trying to access some properties, on the list and map through them, but i get this error:
```
Property 'type' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```
I have already update the Desc with the included code..

Comment: I guess your T needs to extend MappedObject if I understood your new problem: interface IProps<T extends MappedObject>